# Java: open image on a jlabel

Tags: java, swing

I have seen tons of questions about this thing but i just cant completely understand why it doesnt work.
I want to open an image using JFileChooser and then show it on the jLabel on the other jFrame. So why it doesnt work? What is so wrong about it?

```
JFileChooser fileopen = new JFileChooser(); 
int ret = fileopen.showDialog(null, "Open file");
if (ret == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
File file = fileopen.getSelectedFile();
Icon icon = fileopen.getIcon(file);
origin.jLabel1.setIcon(icon);}
```

By the way will it work for .bmp files, not only .jpg, .png and .gif?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use ImageIcon. References can be found here: [ImageIcon java Docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/ImageIcon.html) and [Swing tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/icon.html).

Here is the updated source:

```
  JFileChooser fileopen = new JFileChooser();
    int ret = fileopen.showDialog(null, "Open file");
    if (ret == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {

        File file = fileopen.getSelectedFile();
        ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(file.getPath());
        jLabel1.setIcon(icon);
    }
```